# How to render styles and defining a variable from a React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm setting up a create-react project and currently working on the authentication part to log in into the user profile using JWT.

Currently I am having problem with the styles

Register Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Logo from "./assets/images/logo_transparent.png";

 //redux
 import { connect } from "react-redux";
 //proptypes
 import PropTypes from "prop-types";
 import { register } from "./actions/authActions";


 const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
   "@global": {
   body: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white
    }
   },
 paper: {
marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
display: "flex",
flexDirection: "column",
alignItems: "center"
},
form: {
width: "100%", // Fix IE 11 issue.
marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
},
 submit: {
margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2)
}
 }));

 class Register extends Component {
  state = {

name: "",
email: "",
password: "",
msg: null
};

static propTypes = {
isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
error: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
register: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

onChange = e => {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
 };

onSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const { name, email, password } = this.state;

//create user object
const newUser = {
  name,
  email,
  password
};
//attempt to register
this.props.register(newUser);
};

  render() {
const classes = useStyles();
return (
  <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
    <CssBaseline />
    <div className={classes.paper}>
      <Avatar
        alt="logo"
        src={Logo}
        style={{
          width: 100,
          height: 100
        }}
      />
      <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
        NIK
      </Typography>
      <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
        Sign up
      </Typography>
      <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <TextField
              autoComplete="fname"
              name="fullName"
              variant="outlined"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="fullName"
              label="Full Name"
              autoFocus
            />
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="email"
              label="Email Address"
              name="email"
              autoComplete="email"
            />
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              required
              fullWidth
              name="password"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              id="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              required
              fullWidth
              name="password"
              label="Confirm Password"
              type="password"
              id="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Checkbox value="allowExtraEmails" color="primary" 
                 />
              }
              label="I want to receive inspiration, marketing 
                  promotions and updates via email."
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Button
          type="submit"
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.submit}
        >
          Sign Up
        </Button>
        <Button fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary">
          Home
        </Button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <Grid container justify="flex-end">
          <Grid item>
            <Link href="http://localhost:3000/" variant="body2">
              Already have an account? Sign in
            </Link>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </form>
    </div>
    <Box mt={5}>
      <MadeWithLove />
    </Box>
  </Container>
);
   }
  }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
 error: state.error //getting from reducer
 });

export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 { register } //from redux actions
)(Register); //component
```

The errors are listed below for reference.

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

If I remove the JSX element containing the classes variable (from useStyle), it will work but the styling will be messed up.

Comment: As it says, *"hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component"*, but yours is a *class* component. See https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook; `makeStyles` creates a hook.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an implementation of @material-ui that use React Hooks (in this case makeStyles), which can only be used only inside React Functional Component and not a regular Class Component.

If you change your component from:

```
class Register extends Component {}
```

to:

```
const Register = () => {}
```

you should be able to use it, but you'll need to change the logic inside your Component as you'll need to use also `useState` instead of `this.setState`.

I'll recommend to check the documentation at [@material-ui/styles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) and use the HOC approach specified there if you're not used to work with @material-ui or React Hooks.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It is my first time using @material-ui and I am still very new to React. I will try to use the functional component then.